# Where can I find OPRA data?

Tags: data-request, finance

Where can I find [OPRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Options_Price_Reporting_Authority) data. Here are a few criteria:

1. Preferably free or for a small price;
2. Supports quant API on cloud (so I don't number crunch on my computer);
3. Good reputation company.

Comment: I'll assume you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Options_Price_Reporting_Authority

Comment: I assume you're familiar with http://www.ivolatility.com/ ?